# Handling Sub Menus in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am Trying to automate an web application developed in (SmartGWT technology)In my test case i have to navigate from one menu to other sub menu and click on a option.

My Code:

```
Actions builder1 = new Actions (driver);

WebElement Filterselection = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_DYtable']/tbody[2]/tr[14]/td[2]/nobr"));

builder1.moveToElement(TypeColumn).build().perform();


WebElement  ShowHiddenFilter =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_EAtable']/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[4]/nobr")); 

ShowHiddenFilter.click();
```

I am getting:

> `Error:org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='isc_EAtable']/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[4]/nobr"}`

please see the screen shot of the Menu's which i have to navigate.

Comment: we can't help you without html. also, don't call both `.build().perform()`.  you only need `.perform()` as perform calls build.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[@id='isc_EAtable']/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[4]/nobr
```

CSS or XPATH Use Relative CSS/XPATH. Absolute XPATH will not Work always.

Optimized Way -- Use Relative CSS/XPATH.